# Visual studio web load test

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, visual-studio-2012, extract

We have created web load test using visual studio enterprise edition.
The application is web based asp.net

When we want to extract a value from one of the response,it is not showing up.

What we did.

1. Recorded the journey via web recorder.
2. The request is added as dependent request.
3. We know that on dependent request you can't add the extraction rules
4. We try to take the dependent request out and add as main request using fiddler trace but still no luck

In the fiddler it clearly shows up as response but in the recorded body it is shown up as dependent and hence unable to add the extraction rules

Did anyone come across this scenario? Please let me know how to apply the extraction rules in this case

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: If the string you're looking for is in a dependent request, have you tried writing a web test request plugin that can parse the response from a dependent request?